# Deleting columns from CSV using PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I have a CSV file that has duplicate column headers, so I can't use Import-Csv to do the work. The header names are dynamic. I need to get the third column, the fourth column, and every fourth column after that(ex: starting from 0 columns 2, 3, 7, 11, 15...).

The reason I have duplicate column names is that header 3 needed the same name as header 0, in groups of four. 0 > 3, 4 > 7, 8 > 11...

I used get-Content because I couldn't figure out how to make this work with Import-Csv. I had to use Import-Csv to get the number of columns, which I couldn't figure out with Get-Content.

```
#Rename every fourth column
$file = "C:\Scripts\File.csv"
$data = get-content $file
$step = 4
$csv = Import-Csv "C:\Scripts\File.csv"
$headers = $data | select -first 1
$count = $csv[0].PSObject.Properties | select -Expand Name

for ($i = 0; $i -lt $count.count; $i += $step)
{    
    $headers = $headers -split ","
    $headers[($i + 3)] = $headers[$i]
    $headers[($i + 2)] = "timestamp"
    $headers = $headers -join ","
    $data[0] = $headers
    $data | Set-Content "C:\Scripts\File.csv"
}
```

I can reuse the variable $count if needed (for $count.count), so I don't have to use Import-Csv again.  I'm having trouble figuring out how to get just the columns I need based on number and not header name.

This worked great for getting the third column (2nd if starting from 0), but I'm not sure how to get every fourth after that (3rd if starting from 0)

```
type "C:\Scripts\File.csv" | % { $_.Split(",") | select -skip 2 -first 1 }
```

Screenshots below. Keep in mind I do not know the headers names of every fourth column as they could be anything, I only know which column number the data is in (every fourth column).

[image: Before]
[image: After]

Comment: Is there some reason you can't just specify your own column headers manually with the `-Header` option of `Import-Csv`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd re-think that whole process and start with this:

```
$file = "C:\Scripts\File.csv"
$HeaderCount = ((gc sentlog.csv -TotalCount 1).split(',')).count -1
$CSV = import-csv $file -Header (0..$HeaderCount)
```

Now you can treat those column headings like array indexes to extract out the columns you want.

Use Select -Skip 1 to strip off the original header row.  You can rewrite the property names for export using calculated properties or just create new objects, using property names extracted from the original header row.

OK, based on the posted data, try this:

```
$file = "C:\Scripts\File.csv"
$OutputFile = "C:\Scripts\OutputFile.csv"

$HeaderCount = ((Get-Content $file -TotalCount 1).split(',')).count -1
$CSV = import-csv $file -Header (0..$HeaderCount)

$SelectedColumns = @(2) + ( (0..$HeaderCount) |? { ($_ % 4) -eq 3 } ) -as [string[]]

 $CSV | 
 select $SelectedColumns |
 ConvertTo-CSV -NoTypeInformation |
 Select -Skip 1 |
 Set-Content $OutputFile
```

Comment: That is quite a bit more than I know how to do.  I was thinking of selecting the columns I need and using Add-Content to add them to a CSV, but it doesn't create a new column, it adds everything to the first column below other data.

Comment: I don't think it will as complicated as you're imaging. If you post some sample data and expected output, I'll give you some example code.

Comment: Note that this will not work perfectly if the .csv file uses quoted identifiers and fields contain commas since `Import-Csv` and `ConvertFrom-Csv` both handle those correctly, while `Split(',')` will not.  Example: `$x = '"1","2,3"'; $x | ConvertFrom-Csv -Header $($x.Split(',')) | ft -a`

Comment: @Bacon Bits - I assumed that the split will work based on the fact that the OP is doing it in the code he has now - $headers = $headers -split ",".

Comment: The data contains no quotes and no additional commas. Formatting doesn't seem to work the greatest, so I'll post screenshots of the before and after data.

Comment: It doesn't have to be the exact data, it just needs to have the same structure.

Comment: @mjolinor Yup, just wanted to note it for future purposes. :)

Comment: Posted an sample solution.  You'll need to test that with your data.

Comment: I get this error -- select : Cannot convert System.Int32 to one of the following types {System.String, System.Management.Automation.ScriptBlock}.

Comment: It does work for the third column, timestamp, but no other data is being selected so it's not making it to the new CSV.  The new file only has one column, the timestamp column.

Comment: Look at $HeaderCount and $SelectedColumns.  Do those have the expected values?

Comment: The $selectedcolumns variable has two rows of data, 2 then 3,7,11,etc. I added a three to "2,3,( (0..$Head...)" and it pulled that column (then the variable had three rows of numbers - 2 then 3 then 3, 7, 11,etc). I'm trying to figure out how to rearrange the numbers in the $selectedcolumns variable.

Comment: It's working for me using V4.  I updated the answer with a more explicit array constructor.

Comment: That did it, perfect!  Can you explain how that fixed it?  Thanks again!

Comment: Glad it worked! There seems to be difference in the way it parsed that list of columns.  The updated version is using explicit array addition, vs implicit array construction (using the commas).  What version are you running?

Comment: $PSVersionTable.PSVersion says Major 4. I'm on Win7Pro 64.

Comment: Odd.  I'm running the same.  Don't really have time to try to sort that out right now.  Might start a new question on it. Do you understand how the rest of it works?

Comment: I do understand the script now, very creative. Thanks!